# In theory is it (perversely) legal to use only the accidental reuse of a memory range in the dynamic allocation to synchronize threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-model

In C++, dynamic memory (de)allocation (malloc-free/new-delete) can obviously repeatedly get the same memory range that is free-ed and allocated again in sequence. In multithread C++, that can happen in multiple threads.

Obviously such reuse shouldn't be the problem of the user and he doesn't have to care about it; here is how that is specified in "**Data races**" [[new.delete.dataraces]](http://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.dataraces)

> For purposes of determining the existence of data races, the library
>   versions of operator new, user replacement versions of global operator
>   new, the C standard library functions aligned_­alloc, calloc, and
>   malloc, the library versions of operator delete, user replacement
>   versions of operator delete, the C standard library function free, and
>   the C standard library function realloc shall not introduce a data
>   race ([res.on.data.races]). Calls to these functions that allocate or
>   deallocate a particular unit of storage shall occur in a single total
>   order, and each **such deallocation call shall happen before the next
>   allocation** (if any) in this order.

The last sentence is interesting: not only the reuse of a memory range doesn't cause a conflict, but also that there must exist an *happen before* (HB) relation. Although it doesn't say that the implementation must create the HB relation, and while HB requirements are normally are requirements on the user, since the requirement is conditional and based on a special case created by the implementation (the standard library code), it seems clear that it can only be interpreted as a requirement on the implementation.

It means that in the special case where a subsequent allocation returns a previously freed memory location, there is an implied HB relation with the code that freed it.

Does that really mean that the visibility of any memory operation performed by a thread that does a deallocation can be expected to be extremely rarely guaranteed by code that does a memory allocation?

That would look like an extremely odd burden to put on implementations, only usable by extremely bizarre code that would memorize copies of deleted addresses in the event some other thread gets back these same addresses (all while not creating any synchronization, for example via relaxed atomic RMW operations on pointer representations).

Do real implementations take care to really provide that visibility? Are memory allocation functions treated as either "black box" functions, or as acquire (release) operations by the compiler?

ADDITIONAL PRECISION

Here is a potentially problematic case: the compiler could provide attributes to specify semantic properties of functions (like GCC [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html)) that identify functions that can only affect some memory range (in the current "module", which would be a domain of programming invariants: user, stdlib, other library...). I admit I not worked out the details but it seems intuitively doable and the concepts seem potentially useful for optimization.

There annotations would be invalid if the implementation must provide such guarantee across allocations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194149/discussion-on-question-by-curiousguy-in-theory-is-it-perversely-legal-to-use-o).

Answer (score 1):

Visibility of arbitrary memory operations would not be guaranteed around such allocations.

Each de/allocation needs to be ordered with respect to the others, and allocations which return the same memory as a previous allocation are explicitly ordered. But this does not imply ordering with respect to *other operations* that happened inbetween. That is, it does not imply sequential consistency of all other operations.

Now, other operations can be visible, such as those which happen before the deallocation. But everything that preceded the deallocation does not.

The point of the statement is to make it clear that, if you do get the same memory address as a prior allocation, then the ordering that led you there certainly involved both an allocation and a deallocation of memory involving that address.

Specifications have to be rather pedantic sometimes.

> That would look like an extremely odd burden to put on implementations

Not really. The visibility may only be required with regards to memory de/allocation, but even visibility would hardly be surprising or burdensome.

After all, the heap is a shared resource. So as a shared resource, access to it tends to be locked behind a mutex of some sort. And most mutexes ensure full visibility of everything lock/unlock. And this is important, because managing a heap requires writing heap management data, which must be made visible to other threads that try to allocate it. So you need a fairly broad memory barrier just to do your job as a thread-accessible allocator.

And it's not like anyone mistook a general memory allocator for being a *fast* operation.

So if an implementation did provide full visibility, it would likely be because it's needed for managing heap memory, and other memory accesses that gain visibility just came along for the ride.

> Here is a potentially problematic case: the compiler could provide attributes to specify semantic properties of functions (like GCC Common Function Attributes) that identify functions that can only affect some memory range (in the current "module", which would be a domain of programming invariants: user, stdlib, other library...).

Such a function could not call the compiler-supplied, general-purpose memory allocator. By definition, such a function *requires* having tight control over what memory it uses, and the basic memory allocator doesn't give you that. So if it needs dynamic allocations, it would have to use a specialized allocator, and such an allocator can play by whatever rules it wants.

Comment: I expect memory allocators to be extremely optimized and avoid heavy mutexes and unnecessary synchronization when possible (and probably the use of thread local data). **Can allocators use relaxed atomics to exchange blocks with other pools?**

Comment: @curiousguy: The general-purpose, compiler-supplied allocator? Yeah, it's pretty unlikely that one could write such a thing that doesn't involve a mutex. At some point, you're going to have to go to the OS and ask for pages of memory. And *that* is going to have to lock a mutex. Not to mention the cost of calling an OS function.

Comment: A mutex or a syscall? Either way, it's a black box and serializes access.

Comment: "_Now, other operations can be visible, such as those which happen before the deallocation. But everything that preceded the deallocation does not_" I don't understand

Comment: @curiousguy: "*I don't understand*" If A happens before B, and B happens before C, then A happens before C. So B/C can be the de/allocation, while A/B can be a mutex dependency or something else that creates a "happens before".

Comment: "_So as a shared resource, access to it tends to be locked behind a mutex of some sort._" Wouldn't smaller heaps each protected by its own mutex also work?